# jetpack compose. infinite call to observeAsState

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I monitor the behavior of a variable that is in the viewmodel using the **observeAsState** function. When I get the state I need, I switch to another screen, but after that my program hangs in an endless loop. What am I doing wrong, please tell me?

The image below shows the logs of the monitored variable from the viewmodel

[image]

The code below shows the only function in which I change the value of **_loginStatus**, which I need to track through **observeAsState**. Nowhere else does the value of **_loginStatus** change:

```
fun authorize(automaticLoad: Boolean = false) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        setStatus(Status.Loading())
        repository.authoriseAccount(storedLogin.value.orEmpty().trim(), storedPassword.value.orEmpty().trim(), getApplication()).let {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                when (it) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        
                        _loginStatus.postValue(Status.Success(it.data))

                    }
                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        Log.e("AUTH", "auth error")
                        if (!automaticLoad){
                            _loginStatus.postValue(Status.Error("Incorrect login or password entered"))
                        }
                        else{
                            _loginStatus.postValue(Status.Error())
                        }
                    }

                }
                //_loginStatus.postValue(Status.Ready())
                _loginStatus.setValue(Status.Ready())
            }
        }
    }
```

Code in the Composable function:

```
val status by  viewModel.loginStatus.observeAsState()
    Log.e("tag", status.toString())
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it this way

```
val status by  viewModel.loginStatus.observeAsState()
    Log.e("tag", status.toString())

LaunchedEffect(true) {
     viewModel.authorize()
 }

//whatever you want to do with the status variable
```

The reason is explained here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects